# why are those evidently useless comments kept in by various reviewers?

Tags: discussion, flagging

in this question:

[When and why should the conductor be separate or not from the musicians?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4071/when-and-why-should-the-conductor-be-separate-or-not-from-the-musicians/)

there are comments which are :

```
+1; thank you for your views!
```

a vote **already** counts as a +1, and as a thanks. can anyone tell me how any comment flag reviewers could think this applies as a pertinent comment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those comments were made by the question asker, and are also over two years old.

Comments are not held to the same standards as posts. I see no reason to deny the OP a non-anonymous thank you (votes, by contrast, are anonymous), particularly given that these comments do not crowd out useful information or cause difficulty in understanding.

[Official reference for “don't leave ‘thank you’ comments”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101124/official-reference-for-dont-leave-thank-you-comments)

Generally, as a mod, I don't really want to see flags on innocuous posts that have stood unnoticed for months or years. If something is truly problematic, by all means flag it, but these comments are just not that important.

Comment: `What I do mind is new users who feel compelled to leave a “thank you” comment on every answer to their question;` this is pretty much the case, as every question have had it's `+1; thanks`. two of them are copy/pasta, the third one extends a bit. I haven't reported the third one, only the two first. That being said, I agree

Comment: for what it's worth: after a few months and a [read over there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling), I apologize. I did not realize what a comment flag was nor the role of diamond stars moderator in their processing.